# Error when I read RSS file

Tags: xml, vb.net, rss

I have tried to read from rss file in this URL:
http://www.alarabiya.net/.mrss/ar/sport.xml

This file starts with header:
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

It might be because the version of XML file is 2.0.

I got this error when I executed my code below:

```
Expected DTD markup was not found. Line 1, position 3.
```

The code is working fine with other URL where XML files are in version 1.0.

```
 Dim rssXmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
 rssXmlDoc.Load(http://www.alarabiya.net/.mrss/ar/sport.xml)
 Dim rssNodes As XmlNodeList = rssXmlDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item")
 Dim rssContent As New StringBuilder()
 For Each rssNode As XmlNode In rssNodes
        Dim rssSubNode As XmlNode
        rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("link")
        link = If(rssSubNode IsNot Nothing, rssSubNode.InnerText, "")
        rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("title")
        Dim titlen As String = If(rssSubNode IsNot Nothing, rssSubNode.InnerText, "")
        rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("pubDate")
        ndate = If(rssSubNode IsNot Nothing, rssSubNode.InnerText, "")
        MsgBox(titlen & vbNewLine & link & vbNewLine & ndate)
    Next
```

Please guide me how to solve this problem...

Comment: Did you examine the XML? Is it valid? Looks empty to me.

Comment: It is not empty. You can click on the URL to see the content of file.

Comment: Use a web browser to view source by using menu View : Source. Each message is wrapped in item tag : <item>
      <title>هوساوي يتفق مع أهلي جدة على التجديد لموسمين</title>
      <link>http://www.alarabiya.net/ar/sport/saudi-sport/2015/11/04/هوساوي-يتفق-مع-الأهلي-على-التجديد-لموسمين.html</link>
      <description/>
      <pubDate>Wed, 04 Nov 2015 20:36:24 +0400</pubDate>
      <media:content url="http://vid.alarabiya.net/images/2015/04/25/fd05ddff-ed17-4ad4-9cb4-d196aa4c29a3/fd05ddff-ed17-4ad4-9cb4-d196aa4c29a3_4x3_690x515.jpg"/>
    </item>